# How do you Connect Two Wall Heaters Two 20A breakers and One Thermostat?

Tags: electrical

I have Two 4000w Wall Heaters on Two 20A breakers and One Thermostat.
I actually blew up my new Mysa thermostat trying to upgrade from an old one.
What's the best way to work this problem?

Comment: What is your current wiring configuration?  Or are you wiring this new?  Also I am not surprised your new thermostat blew up, this is actually a real trick.

Comment: What model are you trying to install? Among multiple unanswered variables that create issues the biggest one I see is the MYSA website indicates current products are rated for a maximum 3800 watts. I also don't see any product that will work on multiple circuits.

Comment: That's right - the Mysa thermostat is limited to 3800w. I should have checked before ordering it. I should have just left it alone to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

### You can't. Good news is, you can use normal 'stats like the Nest

Your system uses line-voltage thermostats where the 'stat itself switches high-amperage 240V.  Generally you can't control 2 separate circuits worth of heaters from one such thermostat, because most 2-pole 'stats only switch one pole *thermostatically* and the other pole is only turned off at the bottom (hard off) position. *Your old thermostat is a 2-pole which switches both poles thermostatically, which makes it unique.  You'll be hard pressed to find another one like it.  No smart thermostats exist which are capable of it.*

You must fully separate these 2 circuits, but that is impossible with the readily available stock of thermostats.  Therefore we are left with junking line-voltage control *entirely*, and going with 24V style 'stats.  The 24V control voltage can freely visit both circuits' heaters without restriction.

In this case you have a 24V transformer feeding the "R" and "C" wires.  A relay on each heater is activated by the "W" and "C" wires.  And a thermostat which uses "R" and "W" to call for heat, and "C" to power itself.   Very standard stuff.   Standard color codes are red for R, white for W, and blue for C.

Heaters usually have extra space for this sort of apparatus.  Each heater gets a relay (unless there's an advantage to putting the relays near the breaker panel), and the transformer can go near a relay.

Answer (score 0):

The line voltage thermostat could control one heater plus a relay. The relay could then control the second heater.

You'll still have the problem of a thermostat rated lower than the heater (could use the thermostat to control two relays, though!).